# Create script snippets on VScode Terminal like Termius

Tags: visual-studio-code, termius

is there any way to define custom snippets into the console or WSL Ubuntu throughout the VScode? I saw this really useful feature as a Premium feature on Termius app.
I don't know if the dev team seeing this but if it was the main feature as a sidebar in the terminal, that would be great.